# Fixed div inside a scrollable div - CSS only

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I'm trying to make a div stay at a fixed location inside another div. The containing div is scrollable and his location is not fixed in the screen.

This is what I got so far [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wt7renja/)

The text "fixed text" should stay at the top right corner of the container when scrolling. 
I made 2 copies of the div and kept the same class in order to simulate 2 different locations of the div.

Can it be done with CSS only?

**HTML**

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    fixed text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cont">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    fixed text
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cont{
  width: 400px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.items{
  width: 600px;
}

.item{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.txt{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `overflow: auto` on `items` instead of `cont` element.

```css
.cont {
  width: 400px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.items {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    fixed text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution. This is just a simplified example of my problem. I'll have to check if it doesn't affect other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Create an *extra* wrapper and apply `height` and `overflow` to that - I have added a div `inner` wrapping all the contents of `cont` and applied this to it:

```
.inner {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: inherit;
}
```

See demo below to see what I mean:

```css
.cont {
  width: 400px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  /*overflow-x: auto;*/
  /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
  position: relative;
}
.items {
  width: 600px;
}
.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 10px;
}
.inner {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="txt">
      fixed text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I commented to Nenad, this is just a simplified example of my problem. I'll have to check if it doesn't affect other elements

Answer (score 0):

Add the fixed height and overflow to `.items` instead, so that `.items` scrolls instead of `.cont`, and `.txt` will stay where it is since it is positioned relative to `.cont` and `.cont` isn't scrolling.

```css
.cont{
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.items{
  width: 600px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.txt{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    fixed text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cont">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    fixed text
  </div>
</div>
```